# I can't seem to get the value in the main function to change when using a pointer argument

Tags: c

I think the best way to explain the question is by giving an example:

Why does this output "031" instead of "111"? Also, how would I get it to change the value "a" while only changing the DoSomething function?

```
#include <stdio.h>


void DoSomething(char* a);

int main(){
char a[11] = "031";
DoSomething(a);
printf("%s\n", a);
}

void DoSomething(char* a){
a = "111";
return;
}
```

Thank you, This probably is very simple but I can't seem to get it!

Comment: You need to read books about C programming, like [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/). You should also read the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...) and read *very carefully* [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). You may want to read a [textbook on operating systems](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Comment: Hint: `a = ...` changes a *local variable*. It does not replace anything in the original memory location. Read up on how C strings work, and look at `strcpy()`.

Comment: You could later read some C standard, like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or better. You definitely should use different names for your three different declarations of `a`. If you are allowed to use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile your code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`.

Comment: You could also download then study, for inspiration, the source code of open source programs coded in C, like [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) standalone shell or the [tiny C compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void DoSomething(char* a){
    a = "111";
    return;
}
```

Here, `a` is a local variable. Whatever you assign to this will be invalid once the function returns. If you imagine that since you are passing the address of `a`, `111` should be laid down at that location, you would be wrong. In your `DoSometing` function, `a` is assigned the address of wherever the literal `111` resides and then the function returns making `a` and the address pointed to by `a` invalid.

One solution is to use the `strcpy` function:

```
void DoSomething (char* a){
    strcpy (a, "111");
    return;
}
```

Here, the `strcpy` function will copy `111` from wherever it resides to the address that was passed to `DoSomething`. The address pointed to by `a` is still valid as it was allocated in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

The output is **"031"** instead of **"111"**  because you have used a local variable **a**(in DoSomething function) which points to the **a**(array) in main function. But when you assign the base address of "111" to **a**(of DoSomething function) then you are making the **a**(of DoSomething) pointer to point to "111".The **a** in the main function has no change after making the pointer **a**( of DoSomething function) to point "111" since the a( of DoSomething function) is now pointing to "111".
You are doing nothing but making the pointer to point another string. That's why the array **a**(of main function) has no impact.

if you want the output as "111" then try the below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void DoSomething(char** a);

int main(){
char *a = "031";
DoSomething(&a);
printf("%s\n", a);
}

void DoSomething(char**a){
*a = "111";
return;
}
```

Here I have used double pointer which will contain the address of a(of main function)
and now dereferencing it 1 time and assigning the base address of "111" will  make the pointer a(of main function) to point "111".
I hope it answers your question.